# Regex to validate any kind of date format

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find any kind of date format in a text as:

1. 04.04.17
2. 4/5/2016
3. 6 December 1900
4. 9 Dec 2014
5. 1st of May 1920
6. 2017
7. Dec. 21
8. October 10, 1930
9. October 10th, 2017
10. March 10-12 2015

Years only 1800 until 2017

That's what I have so far:

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?([\/\-\.]|st of\s|nd of\s|rd of\s|th of\s|\s)(Jan.?(uary)?|Feb.?(ruary)?|Mar.?(ch)?|Apr.?(il)?|May|Jun.?(e)?|Jul.?(y)?|Aug.?(ust)?|Sep.?(tember)?|Oct.?(ober)?|Nov.?(ember)?|Dec.?(ember)?|0?[1-9]|1[012])([\/\-\.]|\s)(((18|19)\d{2}|20[01][0-7])|[01][0-7])
```

The expression above can find the formats no. 1 to 5. If I try to work with the question mark quantifier after the first groups to find dates like "Dec. 21" and "2017" it does not work for the other date formats anymore.

Furthermore, the format no. 1 to 7 is more or less `dd/mm/yyyy`. However, format no. 8 to 10 is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Any advice to solve this problem in one regex expression?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Any advice to solve this problem in one regex expression?"  Don't. Use Dave C's suggestion.  And note that you have only listed a small portion of "any kind of date format".  You will probably need to add many more.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: instead of a monster regex, which would be nearly impossible to maintain, how about having an array of regex, one for each format you're accepting. Then loop through your array to see if the input matches any of your regexes. It would be easier to maintain, and likely would run faster, too.

Comment: For performance (if that matters) it can be a good practice to make that array, loop the array to make one longer regex, compile the regex, and then pass the compiled regex to where you want to use it.  If this is just a few regexes it won't matter, but if you get to dozens of regexes making one big one dynamically and compiling will be much faster.